# weird when I pass int parameter I get a different result than when I pass double

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main() {    
        printFinalTemperature(27.0, "Celsius", "Fahrenheit") { 9/5 * it + 32 }
        printFinalTemperature(350.0, "Kelvin", "Celsius") { it - 273.15 }
        printFinalTemperature(10.0, "Fahrenheit", "Kelvin") { 5.0 / 9.0 * (it - 32) + 273.15 }
}


fun printFinalTemperature(
    initialMeasurement: Double, 
    initialUnit: String, 
    finalUnit: String, 
    conversionFormula: (Double) -> Double
) {
    val finalMeasurement = String.format("%.2f", conversionFormula(initialMeasurement)) // two decimal places
    println("$initialMeasurement degrees $initialUnit is $finalMeasurement degrees $finalUnit.")
}
```

it give me this result

27.0 degrees Celsius is 59.00 degrees Fahrenheit.

350.0 degrees Kelvin is 76.85 degrees Celsius.

10.0 degrees Fahrenheit is 260.93 degrees Kelvin.`

but when I write 9.0/5.0 rather than 9/5 I get this result

27.0 degrees Celsius is 80.60 degrees Fahrenheit.

350.0 degrees Kelvin is 76.85 degrees Celsius.

10.0 degrees Fahrenheit is 260.93 degrees Kelvin.

why does the result change when I change int to double ?
what happened behind the scenes ?

Comment: `9 / 5` is `1` in integer math. When you divide two integers, the result is an integer with the remainder thrown away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decimal division versus Integer division are very likely to have large swings in output values.
In the case of your example:

```
Int division   : 9 / 5 = 1
Double division: 9 / 5 = 1.8
```

Integers never store any concept of decimals, in Kotlin the design decision was to use Integer based division following the choices of Java. [Kotlin Discuss](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/dividing-integers/1662)

This specifically works by outright dropping the decimal rather than applying any rounding

Would round up:

```
Int   : 11 / 4 = 2
Double: 11 / 4 = 2.75
```

Would round down:

```
Int   : 9 / 4 = 2
Double: 9 / 4 = 2.25
```

In general, division with a double will give the correct *enough* answer (Floating point math does break down in certain circumstances)

Comment: but I say the function will get double when I declare it

Comment: Yes, you do. The function will first apply the integer division, and then convert to a double to be used for the next operation with the input. The division needs to be doubles used for the 9/5 division to maintain the decimal to receive the correct number for multiplication. Otherwise it will be the integer result of 9/5